Reading & Writing in a file and changing the state of a checkbox depending on true or false (AHK v1)
I have a problem i've lingering on for a whole day. So i have this program that has a config file (need one). That ofc keeps all the settings in it for whenever the program is closed.
Tho i have a problem with the checkboxes atm not wanting to change to checked or unchecked depending on if there is true or false inside the file.
Even tho i do read true or false out of the file, the if functions changing the checked status just doesn't seem to want to work...
As you could see in the code, i've only tried it for one checkbox atm, but it still doesn't wanna seem to work. Help much appreciated!
In here my code/the code that doesn't wanna work:
#SingleInstance Force
setkeydelay, -1
setmousedelay, -1
setbatchlines, -1
SetTitleMatchMode 2

#NoEnv
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%

CoordMode, Tooltip, Relative
CoordMode, Pixel, Relative
CoordMode, Mouse, Relative

; IMPORTANTWHEN CHANGING FILE NAME!!!
versionMacro := "V11.1"


;     CONFIG FILE          ====================================================================================================;

defaultConfigContent := "
(
; DEFAULT SETTINGS
AutoLowerGraphics = true
AutoGraphicsDelay = 50
AutoZoomInCamera = true
AutoZoomDelay = 50
AutoEnableCameraMode = true
AutoCameraDelay = 5
AutoLookDownCamera = true
AutoLookDelay = 200
AutoBlurCamera = true
AutoBlurDelay = 50
RestartDelay = 1000
HoldRodCastDuration = 1000
WaitForBobberDelay = 1000
NavigationKey = '\'

; SHAKE SETTINGS
ShakeMode = 'Click'
FishBarColorTolerance = 0
ClickShakeFailsafe = 20
ClickShakeColorTolerance = 1
ClickScanDelay = 100
RepeatBypassCounter = 10
NavigationShakeFailsafe = 30
NavigationSpamDelay = 10

; MINIGAME SETTINGS
ManualBarSize = 0
BarCalculationFailsafe = 10
BarSizeCalculationColorTolerance = 15
WhiteBarColorTolerance = 5
ArrowColorTolerance = 0
StabilizerLoop = 10
SideBarRatio = 0.8
SideBarWaitMultiplier = 4.5
StableRightMultiplier = 2
StableRightDivision = 1.3
StableLeftMultiplier = 1.8
StableLeftDivision = 1.3
UnstableRightMultiplier = 2.4
UnstableRightDivision = 1.3
UnstableLeftMultiplier = 2.4
UnstableLeftDivision = 1.3
RightAnkleBreakMultiplier = 0.9
LeftAnkleBreakMultiplier = 0.5
)"

filePath := A_ScriptDir "\config.txt"

; Check if the config file exists, and create it if not
IfNotExist, %filePath%
{
    MsgBox, Creating file ; debug
    FileAppend, %defaultConfigContent% , %filePath%
}

; Read the file and split its content into lines
FileRead, fileContent, %filePath%
StringSplit, lines, fileContent, `n ; Split the file content into lines

; Parse each line and extract key-value pairs
Loop, %lines0% ; Loop through the split lines (lines0 contains the count)
{
    line := lines%A_Index% ; Get the current line
    if (line != "") ; Skip empty lines
    {
        pos := InStr(line, "=") ; Find the position of '='
        if (pos)
        {
            key := Trim(SubStr(line, 1, pos - 1)) ; Extract and trim the key
            value := Trim(SubStr(line, pos + 1)) ; Extract and trim the value
            ; Dynamically assign the value to a variable
            if (InStr(Trim(SubStr(line, pos + 2, 2)), "t"))
            {
                %key% := 1
            }
            else if (InStr(Trim(SubStr(line, pos + 2, 2)), "f"))
            {
                %key% := 0
            }
            else
                %key% := value
        }
    }
}



;====================================================================================================;
{
;     GENERAL SETTINGS          ================================================================================================;
; Set to true to automatically lower graphics to 1
; AutoLowerGraphics := true 
; AutoGraphicsDelay := 50

; Set to true to automatically zoom in the camera
; AutoZoomInCamera := true
; AutoZoomDelay := 50

; Set to true to check for camera mode and enable it
; AutoEnableCameraMode := true
; AutoCameraDelay := 5

; Set to true to automatically look down
; AutoLookDownCamera := true
; AutoLookDelay := 200

; Set to true to automatically blur the camera
; AutoBlurCamera := true
; AutoBlurDelay := 50

; How long to wait after fishing before restarting
; RestartDelay := 1000

; How long to hold the cast for before releasing
; HoldRodCastDuration := 1000

; How long to wait for the bobber to land in water
; WaitForBobberDelay := 1000

; Set this to your navigation key, IMPORTANT
; NavigationKey := '\'

;     SHAKE SETTINGS     ====================================================================================================;

; Change to "Navigation" or "Click"
; ShakeMode := "Click"

; Color range to scan for fish bar
; FishBarColorTolerance := 0

; Seconds for click shake to be considered failed
; ClickShakeFailsafe := 20
; Color range to scan for "shake" text
; ClickShakeColorTolerance := 1
; Delay between each scan in miliseconds
; ClickScanDelay := 100
; How many scans before clicking regardless of repeats
; RepeatBypassCounter := 10

; Seconds for navigation shake to be considered failed
; NavigationShakeFailsafe := 30
; Delay between each "S+Enter" in miliseconds
; NavigationSpamDelay := 10

;     MINIGAME SETTINGS     ====================================================================================================;

; Bar size is automatically calculated, set manual value to override
; ManualBarSize := 0
; Seconds for calculation to be considered failed
; BarCalculationFailsafe := 10
; Color range to scan for initial white bar
; BarSizeCalculationColorTolerance := 15

; Color range to scan for minigame white bar
; WhiteBarColorTolerance := 5
; Color range to scan for minigame arrow
; ArrowColorTolerance := 0

; Amount of clicks per action cycle
; StabilizerLoop := 10
; Ratio for bar side maximum hold (1 = max bar|0.5 = half bar)
; SideBarRatio := 0.8
; Multiplier for how long to wait at the sides to prevent bounce
; SideBarWaitMultiplier := 4.5

; Strength for moving right in correct zone
; StableRightMultiplier := 2
; Counter strafe after moving right in correct zone
; StableRightDivision := 1.3
; Strength for moving left in correct zone
; StableLeftMultiplier := 1.8
; Counter strafe after moving left in correct zone
; StableLeftDivision := 1.3

; Strength for moving right when in wrong zone
; UnstableRightMultiplier := 2.4
; Counter strafe after moving right in wrong zone
; UnstableRightDivision := 1.3
; Strength for moving left when in wrong zone
; UnstableLeftMultiplier := 2.4
; Counter strafe after moving left in wrong zone
; UnstableLeftDivision := 1.3

; Strength for moving right after a shift in the middle
; RightAnkleBreakMultiplier := 0.9
; Strength for moving left after a shift in the middle
; LeftAnkleBreakMultiplier := 0.5
}
;====================================================================================================;

MainMenu:
Gui, 1:Add, Button, x117 y128 w170 h20 gConfigMacro, &CONFIG
Gui, 1:Font, s20
Gui, 1:Add, Text, x91 y20 w226 h50, Fisch Macro %versionMacro%
Gui, 1:Font
Gui, 1:Font, s12 Bold
Gui, 1:Add, Button, x117 y85 w170 h40 gStartMacro, &START
Gui, 1:Font
Gui, 1:Add, Button, x117 y151 w170 h20 gExitMacro, &EXIT

Gui, 1:Show, w405 h232, Fisch Macro %versionMacro%
Return

ConfigMacro:
Goto, CONFIG

; StartMacro:
; Goto, START

ExitMacro:
GuiEscape:
GuiClose:
    ExitApp
    
;====================================================================================================;

CONFIG:

   if (AutoLowerGraphics = 1) 
{
    MsgBox, AutoLowerGraphics: 1
    AutoLowerGraphicsChecked := "Checked1"
} else {
    MsgBox, AutoLowerGraphics: 0
    AutoLowerGraphicsChecked := "Checked0"
 }

Gui, 2: Font, s12 Bold
Gui, 2: Add, Text, x16 y8 w212 h23 +0x200, General Settings Config
Gui, 2: Font
if (AutoZoomInCamera) 
    Gui, 2: Add, CheckBox, x24 y56 w121 h24 vAutoZoomInCameraCheckBox Checked, AutoZoomInCamera
 else 
    Gui, 2: Add, CheckBox, x24 y56 w121 h24 vAutoZoomInCameraCheckBox, AutoZoomInCamera

if (AutoEnableCameraMode) 
    Gui, 2: Add, CheckBox, x24 y80 w139 h24 vAutoEnableCameraModeCheckBox Checked, AutoEnableCameraMode
 else 
    Gui, 2: Add, CheckBox, x24 y80 w139 h24 vAutoEnableCameraModeCheckBox, AutoEnableCameraMode

if (AutoLookDownCamera) 
    Gui, 2: Add, CheckBox, x24 y104 w139 h24 vAutoLookDownCameraCheckBox Checked, AutoLookDownCamera
else 
    Gui, 2: Add, CheckBox, x24 y104 w139 h24 vAutoLookDownCameraCheckBox, AutoLookDownCamera

if (AutoBlurCamera) 
    Gui, 2: Add, CheckBox, x24 y128 w121 h24 vAutoBlurCameraCheckBox Checked, AutoBlurCamera
 else 
    Gui, 2: Add, CheckBox, x24 y128 w121 h24 vAutoBlurCameraCheckBox, AutoBlurCamera

Gui, 2: Add, CheckBox, x24 y32 w121 h24 vAutoLowerGraphicsCheckBox %AutoLowerGraphicsChecked%, AutoLowerGraphics

Gui, 2: Add, Edit, x288 y35 w70 h20, 1
Gui, 2: Add, UpDown, gRestartDelay x358 y34 w21 h21 Range1-100000, 1
Gui, 2: Add, Text, x208 y32 w66 h23 +0x200, RestartDelay
Gui, 2: Add, Text, x208 y96 w71 h23 +0x200, NavigationKey
Gui, 2: Add, Edit, gNavigationKey x288 y96 w34 h21 -VScroll
Gui, 2: Font, s12 Bold
Gui, 2: Add, Button, x280 y136 w128 h28 gSubmit, &SUBMIT
Gui, 2: Font
Gui, 2: Add, Button, x280 y168 w128 h20, &ADVANCED CONFIG
Gui, 2: Add, DropDownList, x288 y66 w120, Click||Navigation
Gui, 2: Add, Text, x208 y64 w66 h23 +0x200, ShakeMode

Gui, 2: Show, w430 h195, Config
Return

Submit:
FileRead, fileContent, %filePath%

 ; Get the values from the GUI controls
    Gui, 2: Submit, NoHide ; Save the GUI values to variables

    ; Update the config content
    updatedConfigContent := fileContent ; Start with the existing file content

    ; Update the AutoLowerGraphics setting based on the checkbox
    if (AutoLowerGraphicsCheckbox = 1) ; If checked
        updatedConfigContent := RegExReplace(updatedConfigContent, "(AutoLowerGraphics = ).*", "$1true")
    else ; If unchecked
        updatedConfigContent := RegExReplace(updatedConfigContent, "(AutoLowerGraphics = ).*", "$1false")

    ; Now, write the updated config content back to the file
    FileDelete, %filePath% ; Delete the old config file
    FileAppend, %updatedConfigContent%, %filePath% ; Write the new config content to the file

    MsgBox, Settings updated successfully!

Gui, 2: Destroy
Return

RestartDelay:
Return

NavigationKey:
Return

ShakeMode:
Return

return

I tried a handfull of different things. Like putting my if in a different place etc. Tho with bad luck it didn't seem to work at all. The main problem seems to be that the if just doesn't want to work with me xd.

You need to reload the configuration each time the config button is triggered. Therefore, I moved the configuration load to a label, which is called both at the start of the script and within the config button's action.
#SingleInstance Force
setkeydelay,        -1
setmousedelay,      -1
setbatchlines,      -1
SetTitleMatchMode   2

#NoEnv
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%

CoordMode, Tooltip, Relative
CoordMode, Pixel, Relative
CoordMode, Mouse, Relative

; IMPORTANTWHEN CHANGING FILE NAME!!!
versionMacro := "V11.1"


;     CONFIG FILE          ====================================================================================================;

defaultConfigContent := "
(
; DEFAULT SETTINGS
AutoLowerGraphics = true
AutoGraphicsDelay = 50
AutoZoomInCamera = true
AutoZoomDelay = 50
AutoEnableCameraMode = true
AutoCameraDelay = 5
AutoLookDownCamera = true
AutoLookDelay = 200
AutoBlurCamera = true
AutoBlurDelay = 50
RestartDelay = 1000
HoldRodCastDuration = 1000
WaitForBobberDelay = 1000
NavigationKey = '\'

; SHAKE SETTINGS
ShakeMode = 'Click'
FishBarColorTolerance = 0
ClickShakeFailsafe = 20
ClickShakeColorTolerance = 1
ClickScanDelay = 100
RepeatBypassCounter = 10
NavigationShakeFailsafe = 30
NavigationSpamDelay = 10

; MINIGAME SETTINGS
ManualBarSize = 0
BarCalculationFailsafe = 10
BarSizeCalculationColorTolerance = 15
WhiteBarColorTolerance = 5
ArrowColorTolerance = 0
StabilizerLoop = 10
SideBarRatio = 0.8
SideBarWaitMultiplier = 4.5
StableRightMultiplier = 2
StableRightDivision = 1.3
StableLeftMultiplier = 1.8
StableLeftDivision = 1.3
UnstableRightMultiplier = 2.4
UnstableRightDivision = 1.3
UnstableLeftMultiplier = 2.4
UnstableLeftDivision = 1.3
RightAnkleBreakMultiplier = 0.9
LeftAnkleBreakMultiplier = 0.5
)"

Gosub, Load_config  ;   to load the content or create the default content

;====================================================================================================;
{
;     GENERAL SETTINGS          ================================================================================================;
; Set to true to automatically lower graphics to 1
; AutoLowerGraphics := true 
; AutoGraphicsDelay := 50

; Set to true to automatically zoom in the camera
; AutoZoomInCamera := true
; AutoZoomDelay := 50

; Set to true to check for camera mode and enable it
; AutoEnableCameraMode := true
; AutoCameraDelay := 5

; Set to true to automatically look down
; AutoLookDownCamera := true
; AutoLookDelay := 200

; Set to true to automatically blur the camera
; AutoBlurCamera := true
; AutoBlurDelay := 50

; How long to wait after fishing before restarting
; RestartDelay := 1000

; How long to hold the cast for before releasing
; HoldRodCastDuration := 1000

; How long to wait for the bobber to land in water
; WaitForBobberDelay := 1000

; Set this to your navigation key, IMPORTANT
; NavigationKey := '\'

;     SHAKE SETTINGS     ====================================================================================================;

; Change to "Navigation" or "Click"
; ShakeMode := "Click"

; Color range to scan for fish bar
; FishBarColorTolerance := 0

; Seconds for click shake to be considered failed
; ClickShakeFailsafe := 20
; Color range to scan for "shake" text
; ClickShakeColorTolerance := 1
; Delay between each scan in miliseconds
; ClickScanDelay := 100
; How many scans before clicking regardless of repeats
; RepeatBypassCounter := 10

; Seconds for navigation shake to be considered failed
; NavigationShakeFailsafe := 30
; Delay between each "S+Enter" in miliseconds
; NavigationSpamDelay := 10

;     MINIGAME SETTINGS     ====================================================================================================;

; Bar size is automatically calculated, set manual value to override
; ManualBarSize := 0
; Seconds for calculation to be considered failed
; BarCalculationFailsafe := 10
; Color range to scan for initial white bar
; BarSizeCalculationColorTolerance := 15

; Color range to scan for minigame white bar
; WhiteBarColorTolerance := 5
; Color range to scan for minigame arrow
; ArrowColorTolerance := 0

; Amount of clicks per action cycle
; StabilizerLoop := 10
; Ratio for bar side maximum hold (1 = max bar|0.5 = half bar)
; SideBarRatio := 0.8
; Multiplier for how long to wait at the sides to prevent bounce
; SideBarWaitMultiplier := 4.5

; Strength for moving right in correct zone
; StableRightMultiplier := 2
; Counter strafe after moving right in correct zone
; StableRightDivision := 1.3
; Strength for moving left in correct zone
; StableLeftMultiplier := 1.8
; Counter strafe after moving left in correct zone
; StableLeftDivision := 1.3

; Strength for moving right when in wrong zone
; UnstableRightMultiplier := 2.4
; Counter strafe after moving right in wrong zone
; UnstableRightDivision := 1.3
; Strength for moving left when in wrong zone
; UnstableLeftMultiplier := 2.4
; Counter strafe after moving left in wrong zone
; UnstableLeftDivision := 1.3

; Strength for moving right after a shift in the middle
; RightAnkleBreakMultiplier := 0.9
; Strength for moving left after a shift in the middle
; LeftAnkleBreakMultiplier := 0.5
}
;====================================================================================================;

MainMenu:
Gui, 1:Add, Button, x117 y128 w170 h20 gConfigMacro, &CONFIG
Gui, 1:Font, s20
Gui, 1:Add, Text, x91 y20 w226 h50, Fisch Macro %versionMacro%
Gui, 1:Font
Gui, 1:Font, s12 Bold
Gui, 1:Add, Button, x117 y85 w170 h40 gStartMacro, &START
Gui, 1:Font
Gui, 1:Add, Button, x117 y151 w170 h20 gExitMacro, &EXIT

Gui, 1:Show, w405 h232, Fisch Macro %versionMacro%
Return

ConfigMacro:
Goto, CONFIG

; StartMacro:
; Goto, START

ExitMacro:
GuiEscape:
GuiClose:
    ExitApp
    
;====================================================================================================;

CONFIG:
Gosub, Load_config  ;   to load the content or create the default content
   if (AutoLowerGraphics = 1) 
{
    MsgBox, AutoLowerGraphics: 1
    AutoLowerGraphicsChecked := "Checked1"
} else {
    MsgBox, AutoLowerGraphics: 0
    AutoLowerGraphicsChecked := "Checked0"
 }

Gui, 2: Font, s12 Bold
Gui, 2: Add, Text, x16 y8 w212 h23 +0x200, General Settings Config
Gui, 2: Font
if (AutoZoomInCamera) 
    Gui, 2: Add, CheckBox, x24 y56 w121 h24 vAutoZoomInCameraCheckBox Checked, AutoZoomInCamera
 else 
    Gui, 2: Add, CheckBox, x24 y56 w121 h24 vAutoZoomInCameraCheckBox, AutoZoomInCamera

if (AutoEnableCameraMode) 
    Gui, 2: Add, CheckBox, x24 y80 w139 h24 vAutoEnableCameraModeCheckBox Checked, AutoEnableCameraMode
 else 
    Gui, 2: Add, CheckBox, x24 y80 w139 h24 vAutoEnableCameraModeCheckBox, AutoEnableCameraMode

if (AutoLookDownCamera) 
    Gui, 2: Add, CheckBox, x24 y104 w139 h24 vAutoLookDownCameraCheckBox Checked, AutoLookDownCamera
else 
    Gui, 2: Add, CheckBox, x24 y104 w139 h24 vAutoLookDownCameraCheckBox, AutoLookDownCamera

if (AutoBlurCamera) 
    Gui, 2: Add, CheckBox, x24 y128 w121 h24 vAutoBlurCameraCheckBox Checked, AutoBlurCamera
 else 
    Gui, 2: Add, CheckBox, x24 y128 w121 h24 vAutoBlurCameraCheckBox, AutoBlurCamera

Gui, 2: Add, CheckBox, x24 y32 w121 h24 vAutoLowerGraphicsCheckBox %AutoLowerGraphicsChecked%, AutoLowerGraphics

Gui, 2: Add, Edit, x288 y35 w70 h20, 1
Gui, 2: Add, UpDown, gRestartDelay x358 y34 w21 h21 Range1-100000, 1
Gui, 2: Add, Text, x208 y32 w66 h23 +0x200, RestartDelay
Gui, 2: Add, Text, x208 y96 w71 h23 +0x200, NavigationKey
Gui, 2: Add, Edit, gNavigationKey x288 y96 w34 h21 -VScroll
Gui, 2: Font, s12 Bold
Gui, 2: Add, Button, x280 y136 w128 h28 gSubmit, &SUBMIT
Gui, 2: Font
Gui, 2: Add, Button, x280 y168 w128 h20, &ADVANCED CONFIG
Gui, 2: Add, DropDownList, x288 y66 w120, Click||Navigation
Gui, 2: Add, Text, x208 y64 w66 h23 +0x200, ShakeMode

Gui, 2: Show, w430 h195, Config
Return

Submit:
FileRead, fileContent, %filePath%

 ; Get the values from the GUI controls
    Gui, 2: Submit, NoHide ; Save the GUI values to variables

    ; Update the config content
    updatedConfigContent := fileContent ; Start with the existing file content

    ; Update the AutoLowerGraphics setting based on the checkbox
    if (AutoLowerGraphicsCheckbox = 1) ; If checked
        updatedConfigContent := RegExReplace(updatedConfigContent, "(AutoLowerGraphics = ).*", "$1true")
    else ; If unchecked
        updatedConfigContent := RegExReplace(updatedConfigContent, "(AutoLowerGraphics = ).*", "$1false")

    ; Now, write the updated config content back to the file
    FileDelete, %filePath% ; Delete the old config file
    FileAppend, %updatedConfigContent%, %filePath% ; Write the new config content to the file

    MsgBox, Settings updated successfully!

Gui, 2: Destroy
Return

RestartDelay:
Return

NavigationKey:
Return

ShakeMode:
Return


load_config:
    ; THIS BLOCK NEED TO BE LOADED AGAIN IN EACH gConfigMacro
    filePath := A_ScriptDir "\config.txt"

    ; Check if the config file exists, and create it if not
    IfNotExist, %filePath%
    {
        MsgBox, Creating file ; debug
        FileAppend, %defaultConfigContent% , %filePath%
    }

    ; Read the file and split its content into lines
    FileRead, fileContent, %filePath%
    StringSplit, lines, fileContent, `n ; Split the file content into lines

    ; Parse each line and extract key-value pairs
    Loop, %lines0% ; Loop through the split lines (lines0 contains the count)
    {
        line := lines%A_Index% ; Get the current line
        if (line != "") ; Skip empty lines
        {
            pos := InStr(line, "=") ; Find the position of '='
            if (pos)
            {
                key := Trim(SubStr(line, 1, pos - 1)) ; Extract and trim the key
                value := Trim(SubStr(line, pos + 1)) ; Extract and trim the value
                ; Dynamically assign the value to a variable
                if (InStr(Trim(SubStr(line, pos + 2, 2)), "t"))
                {
                    %key% := 1
                }
                else if (InStr(Trim(SubStr(line, pos + 2, 2)), "f"))
                {
                    %key% := 0
                }
                else
                    %key% := value
            }
        }
    }
Return

